# How to make crosstab query in mysql

Tags: mysql, crystal-reports

I'm using MySQL. This is table i have

```
Level     Programmingtime    Clientname     projectid
0             128              abc             3
1             32               abc             3
2             126              abc             3
3             541              abc             3
4             452              abc             3
1             32               abc             3
```

But now i have to show this data in crystal report in such a format like

```
projectid  level0              level1      level2   level3   level4
3          128                 32+32=(64)     126      541      452
           (programmingtime)
```

Please tell me what will be the my syntax for such a difficult logic.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the levels known? (is it just 0-5 throughout the whole data set) ?

Comment: Yes levels are known? We have 0,1,2,3,4 levels not more than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the levels are known, you can simply do:

```
SELECT
    projectid,
    SUM(CASE WHEN level = 0 THEN programmingtime ELSE 0 END) AS level0,
    SUM(CASE WHEN level = 1 THEN programmingtime ELSE 0 END) AS level1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN level = 2 THEN programmingtime ELSE 0 END) AS level2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN level = 3 THEN programmingtime ELSE 0 END) AS level3,
    SUM(CASE WHEN level = 4 THEN programmingtime ELSE 0 END) AS level4
FROM
    tbl
GROUP BY
    projectid
```